# why will laravel say all of a sudden Cannot end a section without first starting one in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

`@section("page_title", "Home Page")@stop
@section("body_class", "page-homepage navigation-fixed-top page-slider")@stop`

The above code works just fine for as long as I can remember then yesterday, I ran `composer install` then aborted in the middle of it.

Afterwards, I started getting the error `Cannot end a section without first starting one`. I realized the `@stop` must be removed. I removed it, and everything is fine now, however, I will like to know why `@stop` suddenly started giving problems.

The version of laravel I was using when `@stop` started giving problems is `Laravel Framework version 5.1.23 (LTS)` and the current version which is giving problems with `@stop` is `Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like thsi

```
@section('page_title')

....here page title 

@endsection
```

**OR**

```
<head>
    @include('includes.title')
</head>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I wanted to know is why `@stop` started giving errors all of a sudden. I have fixed the issue already

Comment: check documendation